# the decorator in python confused me

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

i have a simple decorator,the output confused me.

```
def deco(func):
   def kdeco():
      print("before myfunc() called.")
      func()
      print("  after myfunc() called.")
   return kdeco

@deco
def myfunc():
   print(" myfunc() called.")

myfunc()

before myfunc() called.
 myfunc( deco(myfunc)()) called.
  after myfunc() called.

deco(myfunc)()

before myfunc() called.
before myfunc() called.
 myfunc() called.
  after myfunc() called.
  after myfunc() called.
```

i know the output of myfunc(),but the output of deco(myfunc)() confused me,whay the output of deco(myfunc)()  can not be either of them in the following?

status one:

```
before myfunc() called.
before myfunc() called.
 myfunc() called.
 myfunc() called.
  after myfunc() called.
  after myfunc() called.
```

status two:

```
before myfunc() called.
 myfunc( deco(myfunc)()) called.
  after myfunc() called.
before myfunc() called.
 myfunc( deco(myfunc)()) called.
  after myfunc() called.
```

Comment: `deco(myfunc())` is equivalent to `deco(deco(myfunc))()` when there is no decorator on `myfunc()`, as you can see, the outer `deco` calls the inner `deco`, which in turn calls `myfunc`.

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Comment: As a side note: Don't indent with 3 spaces. PEP 8 recommends 4 spaces. The only good reason to violate this is to condense something that would otherwise be too wide (e.g., asking for help on SO with some code that you inherited that has unreasonable nesting or overly-complex one-liners), in which case 2 spaces is better than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are actually just a shortcut to something you can do manually. This code:

```
@deco
def myfunc():
    print(" myfunc() called.")
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def myfunc():
    print(" myfunc() called.")
myfunc = deco(myfunc)
```

For the sake of discussing this, let's say the original were still available as `original_myfunc` (even though in reality it isn't).

So, when you do this:

```
deco(myfunc)()
```

What you end up calling is:

```
deco(deco(original_myfunc))()
```

And if you trace through that, it should be obvious why it prints what you expected. But let's do the exercise anyway.

First, you call `deco(original_myfunc)`, and it does this:

```
def kdeco():
   print("before myfunc() called.")
   original_myfunc()
   print("  after myfunc() called.")
```

return kdeco

So that returns a function that prints the "before", calls `original_myfunc`, then prints the "after".

And now we pass `deco(original_myfunc)` to `deco` again, which does this:

```
def kdeco():
   print("before myfunc() called.")
   deco(original_myfunc)()
   print("  after myfunc() called.")
return kdeco
```

So, that returns a function that prints the "before", then calls `deco(original_myfunc)`—which itself prints the "before", calls `original_myfunc`, and prints "after"—then prints "after".

That's why you get the output you do.

Answer (score 4):

`myfunc` is itself already wrapped by your decorator. The name `myfunc` no longer points to the original method, it now points to the return value of `deco(myfunc)`:

```
>>> def deco(func):
...    def kdeco():
...       print("before myfunc() called.")
...       func()
...       print("  after myfunc() called.")
...    return kdeco
... 
>>> @deco
... def myfunc():
...    print(" myfunc() called.")
... 
>>> myfunc
<function kdeco at 0x10068cb18>
```

That's because the `@decorator` syntax is the same as:

```
def myfunc():
    # body of function
myfunc = deco(myfunc)
```

So `myfunc` is already producing the lines `before ..`, then `.. called`, then `after ..`. Now you wrap that *again*. The wrapper prints `before ..`, calls the wrapped `myfunc` (itself already wrapped), which prints `before ..`, then `.. called`, then `after ..`, and then the wrapper prints `after ..`.

In a diagram:

```
call wrapped myfunc():
    kdeco: "before .."
    call original myfunc()
        original myfunc: ".. called"
    kdeco: "after .."

call deco(myfunc)():
    kdeco: "before .."
    call wrapped myfunc():
        kdeco: "before .."
        call original myfunc()
            original myfunc: ".. called"
        kdeco: "after .."
    kdeco: "after .."
```

Comment: After reading this through, it has almost exactly the same info as my answer, and was posted at exactly the same time, but I think it's more readable, so +1, and hopefully it gets accepted.

Comment: @abarnert and 8 years later, the OP switched to yours! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The decorated function is only called once, hence it cannot claim to have been called twice.